# Derivation of Call Delta from Black Scholes Model

Tags: black-scholes, delta, derivation

How is call delta mathematically derived from Black Scholes Model (without approximation) ? Please help me understand each step mathematically. And how it is approximated to say that delta is the  probability of option expiring in the money?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a mathematical derivation of the Black-Scholes delta.

The call option price under the BS model is
$$ C = S_0 N(d_1) - e^{-rT} K N(d_2) \quad\text{with}\quad 
d_{1,2} = \frac{\log(S_0\,e^{rT}/K)}{\sigma\sqrt{T}} \pm \frac12 \sigma\sqrt{T}, $$
where $N(x)$ is the CDF of standard normal.

Using the properties,
$$ \frac{\partial d_1}{\partial S_0} = \frac{\partial d_2}{\partial S_0} = \frac{1}{S_0\sigma\sqrt{T}}
$$
and
\begin{gather*}
    d_1^2 - d_2^2 = (A+B)^2 - (A-B)^2 = 4AB = 2\log(S_0\,e^{rT}/K)\\
    \quad\text{where}\quad A = \frac{\log(S_0\,e^{rT}/K)}{\sigma\sqrt{T}} \quad\text{and}\quad B = \frac{\sigma\sqrt{T}}{2},
\end{gather*}
we differentiate $C$ with resect to the spot price $S_0$:
\begin{align*}
    D &= \frac{\partial C}{\partial S_0} = \frac{\partial}{\partial S_0}\left( S_0 N(d_1) - e^{-rT} K N(d_2) \right) \\
    &= N(d_1) + S_0 n(d_1) \frac{\partial d_1}{\partial S_0} - e^{-rT} K n(d_2)
    \frac{\partial d_2}{\partial S_0} \\
    &= N(d_1) + \frac{n(d_1)}{\sigma\sqrt{T}} \left( 1 -  e^{(d_1^2-d_2^2)/2}\frac{K}{S_0e^{rT}} \right) \\
    &= N(d_1) + \frac{n(d_1)}{\sigma\sqrt{T}} \left( 1 -  \frac{S_0e^{rT}}{K}\cdot\frac{K}{S_0e^{rT}}
    \right) = N(d_1).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

Look [here](https://quantpie.co.uk/bsm_formula/bs_delta.php) for a detailed derivation of the formula for $\Delta$ (be aware that this particular website uses $r_d$ to denote the risk-free rate and $r_f$ to denote the dividend yield). You can always ask for more specific help regarding a particular step in the derivation.

It is easy to see that $\mathbb{Q}[\{S_T\geq K\}]= \Phi(d_2)$. Just replace $S_T=S_0\exp\left(\left( r-q-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)T +\sigma\sqrt{T}Z\right)$ where $Z\sim N(0,1)$ and isolate $Z$ on the left-hand side. This is the *risk-neutral* probability of expiring ITM. Note that $\Delta=\Phi(d_1)=\Phi(d_2+\sigma\sqrt{T})\approx \Phi(d_2)$. This is since $\sigma\sqrt{T}$ is typically very small.

Comment: That derivation is excellent but it starts with a small typo: in BSCallPrice the roles of $r_f$ the risk free rate and $r_d$ the dividend rate are reversed.

Comment: I think it's not a typo because they use $r_f$ constantly and (as far as I checked) consistently to denote the dividend yield and $r_d$ as risk-free interest rate. So I believe they do this intentionally. However, I do agree with you that this notation is odd because $r_f$ should be the risk-free rate (or perhaps the rate in a foreign currcency) but not the dividend yield.

Comment: But I edited my answer and highlighted that notation issue. Thank you for the hint, Alex!

Comment: Sorry to bother, but I did not get the point how N(d1) is differentiated w.r.t. S and converted to n(d1)*d(d1)/dS. How is a PDF differentiated? Pls help me understand this. Thanks.

Comment: @KeSchn: the web site author says he indeed was thinking in an FX context so $r_f$ = foreign rate, $r_d$ = domestic rate.

Comment: @Quantfint A pdf (probability density function) is a function and can be differentiated like any other function. Let $n(x)=\varphi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}x^2\right)$. Differentiating the cdf $N(x)=\Phi(x)$ works by the chain rule, i.e. $N(d_1(x))=n(d_1(x)){d_1}'(x)$.

Comment: @KeSchn N(d1) =[ ln(S/K) +(rf +σ^2)*t]/σsqrt(t). How come we came to define n(d1) as above?I am unable to connect N(d1) and n(d1). This may sound sound too basic but please help me understand this.

Comment: N represents the cumulative normal distribution, and n represents the normal density. Cumulative is integral of density, so density is then derivative of the cumulative - remember integral is anti-derivative, so derivative of anti--derivative is then the function. For technical approach, please see Leibniz rule (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule). As @KeSchn outlined above, if we take derivative of N(s), we get n(s), and if we want to take derivative of N(d_1) where d_1 is a function of s, we will need to add chain rule:  n(d1)*d(d1)/dS

Comment: A reminder what N(.) and n(.) look like https://dwaincsql.files.wordpress.com/2015/05/normal-pdf-cdf-1.png